# Python: Dealing with multiple entries/rows for the same ID

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python. I'm currently working on a data set where there are multiple entries/rows for the same ID and I would like python to return the ID count that meets the a few conditions.

E.g. Count the number of families where the (condition 1) family members all dislike apples and  (condition 2) has at least one that likes oranges.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkVfk.png)

I'm not familiar in dealing with multiple entries/rows for the same ID

Comment: The format of your data set is unclear. Please add it. Pandas is a convenient and fast way of working with data sets.

Comment: Hi @VictorLinde, I have attached a table. Care to share what function should I be looking at?

Comment: Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This help others to answer the question.